# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while plot showing

Tags: python, numpy

I have such Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.int(x)

x = np.arange(1, 15.1, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

And such error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" is raised when the function expects a single value but you pass an array instead.

`np.int` was an alias for the built-in `int`, which is deprecated in numpy v1.20. The argument for int should be a scalar and it does not accept array-like objects. In general, if you want to apply a function to each element of the array, you can use [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return int(x)
f2 = np.vectorize(f)
x = np.arange(1, 15.1, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, f2(x))
plt.show()
```

You can skip the definition of f(x) and just pass the function `int` to the vectorize function: `f2 = np.vectorize(int)`.

Note that `np.vectorize` is just a convenience function and basically a for loop. That will be inefficient over large arrays. Whenever you have the possibility, use truly vectorized functions or methods (like `astype(int)` as [@FFT suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42350817/2285236)).

Comment: Cleaner and I imagine also faster (I should test). I still have to learn the learn the intricacies of numpy for things like this :)

Comment: Interestingly enough, my answer appears to be faster and I gave the reasoning behind investigation but I don't know the true reason for performance difference. Perhaps someone will shed some light :)

Comment: `np.int` is just a confusing way to spell `int`. Never use the former. Your code can be simplified to `f = int`.

Comment: @ayhan: What if I want to convert `numpy array` to an _object_ , which I can insert into `MongoDB` is `pickling` the way to go ahead?

Comment: np.int() is deprecated.

Answer (score 44):

Use:

```
x.astype(int)
```

Here is the [reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).

Comment: This answer works compared to the accepted answer, np.int() is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

`dataframe['column'].squeeze()` should solve this. It basically changes the dataframe column to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Take note of what is printed for `x`. You are trying to convert an array (basically just a list) into an int. `length-1` would be an array of a single number, which I assume numpy just treats as a float. You could do this, but it's not a purely-numpy solution.

EDIT: I was involved in a post a couple of weeks back where numpy was slower an operation than I had expected and I realised I had fallen into a default mindset that numpy was always the way to go for speed. Since my answer was not as clean as ayhan's, I thought I'd use this space to show that this is another such instance to illustrate that `vectorize` is around 10% slower than building a list in Python. I don't know enough about numpy to explain why this is the case but perhaps someone else does?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

# My original answer
def f(x):
    rebuilt_to_plot = []
    for num in x:
        rebuilt_to_plot.append(np.int(num))
    return rebuilt_to_plot

for t in range(10000):
    x = np.arange(1, 15.1, 0.1)
    plt.plot(x, f(x))

time_end = datetime.datetime.now()

# Answer by ayhan
def f_1(x):
    return np.int(x)

for t in range(10000):
    f2 = np.vectorize(f_1)
    x = np.arange(1, 15.1, 0.1)
    plt.plot(x, f2(x))

time_end_2 = datetime.datetime.now()

print time_end - time_start
print time_end_2 - time_end
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case the output has to be a rounded `int` values.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([2.34, 2.56, 3.12])
output = np.round(arr).astype(int)

print(output)
# array([2, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return np.array(list(map(np.int, x)))

x = np.arange(1, 15.1, 0.1)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

using np.array(list(map(np.int, x))) will converge numpy array to scaler value and fix the issue for more detail visit this [detailed article](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/only-size-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-fix/).