# Issue in plotting array in python

Tags: python

**TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def myfunction(x):
    return np.int(x)
myfunction2 = np.vectorize(myfunction)
x = np.array([0, math.pi/100, 2*math.pi])
y = math.sin(x)
plt.plot(myfunction2(x),y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while plot showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680402/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-plot-sh)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems I see. First, you need to use `np.sin` in order to apply it to the entire vector. Second, your definition of x is only 3 elements long. I believe you are trying to use `np.arange`. Try `x = np.arange(0,2*math.pi,math.pi/100,dtype='float32')` instead.