# only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars - what is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

What is wrong with this code, please. I obtained an error:

```
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Code:

```
import math 
import numpy as np
# Electrostatic electron waves in plasmas
e = 1.602176634e-19
m_e = 9.1093837015e-31
K_B = 1.380649e-23
k = np.arange(0, 10, 0.002)
eps_0 = 8.8541878128e-12
T_e = 5000
n_0 = 10000
v_T = math.sqrt(2*K_B*T_e/m_e)                      # thermal spped of electrons
omega_p = math.sqrt(n_0*e**2/(eps_0*m_e))           # dispersion relation for plasma oscillations
omega = math.sqrt(omega_p**2+3/(2*k**2*v_T**2))
```

Comment: `math.sqrt` only works for scalars. Since `k` is a numby array you need to use `np.sqrt`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while plot showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680402/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-plot-sh)