# I keep getting ' only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars' and I don't know why

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to graph a Blackbody's radiated power per unit energy range.
My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

h = 6.626*(10**(-34))
c = 3*(10**8)
k = 1.38*(10**(-23))
T = 1000

x = np.array(range(100))
y = (x**3)/((math.exp(x/(k*T)))-1)

# Create the plot
plt.plot(x,y)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

And I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-86ad11932249> in <module>
      9 
     10 x = np.array(range(100))
---> 11 y = (x**3)/((math.exp(x/(k*T)))-1)
     12 
     13 # Create the plot

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Could someone explain why what I have is wrong?

Comment: `math.exp` calculates exponent of single variable and `np.exp` calculates it for every item of array. You need to operate on arrays

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars while plot showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680402/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-plot-sh)

Answer (score 2):

It is because `math.exp()` requires a scalar variable, but array enters in your code.
In addition, I think you are not familiar with numpy.
Try this code.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

h = 6.626*(10**(-34))
c = 3*(10**8)
k = 1.38*(10**(-23))
T = 1000

x = np.arange(100) # np.arange is more efficient
y = (x**3) / (np.exp(x/(k*T))-1)

# Create the plot
plt.plot(x,y)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Note that K * T is so small, (np.exp(x/(k*T))-1) returns array including infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `math` with `np`. However, you might want to rewrite your equation as the denominator returns `inf` all of the time (except for `x[0]=0`).