# How do I take the natural log of this list?

Tags: python

I have a function which was defined as x^2+y^2. I calculated the result and got a list of values which is given below here.

```
1.0952339599999999e+38 1.4753378437270275e+38 2.1455313512291806e+38
3.105814482506459e+38 4.356187237558863e+38 5.896649616386393e+38
7.727201618989048e+38 9.847843245366828e+38 1.2258574495519736e+39
1.495939536944777e+39 1.7950305867150923e+39 2.123130598862921e+39
2.4802395733882622e+39 2.866357510291115e+39 3.2814844095714816e+39
3.72562027122936e+39 4.198765095264751e+39 4.700918881677654e+39
5.232081630468072e+39 5.792253341635999e+39 6.381434015181441e+39
6.999623651104394e+39 7.646822249404861e+39 8.323029810082839e+39
9.028246333138334e+39 9.762471818571335e+39 1.0525706266381852e+40
1.1317949676569877e+40 1.2139202049135423e+40 1.2989463384078474e+40
1.3868733681399042e+40 1.4777012941097121e+40 1.571430116317271e+40.....
```

And the list contains 150 other such numbers similar to the ones displayed above.

I need to take the natural log of all these numbers but the error reported is

```
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

This is the code for my function

```
may =(y2+x2)
june = math.log(may)
print(june)
```

I do not know other methods that I can use so any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use numpy for this kind of thing

Comment: You appear to have a `numpy` array here - if so, use numpy's functions rather than the `math` module (which only works in individual numbers).  So, `june = np.log(may)`.

Comment: I did use the lumpy function but it reports this error--
'float' object has no attribute 'log'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing a list to a function that takes a single value. This could be solved by using a for loop to operate on each value or by vectorizing the code using the numpy library. More information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680402/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-plot-sh) post.