# Numpy function type error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, deep-learning, softmax

```
class GCN:
  def __init__(self,alpha,adj,feature,hiddenlayer_neurons,output_layer_neurons):
    self.alpha=alpha
    self.adj=adj
    self.feature=feature
    self.hiddenlayer_neurons=hiddenlayer_neurons
    self.output_layer_neurons=output_layer_neurons
  
  def weightlayers(self):
    self.weights1= np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=0.5,size=(features.shape[1],self.hiddenlayer_neurons))
    print(features.shape)
    print(adj.shape)
    self.weights2= np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=0.5,size=(self.hiddenlayer_neurons,self.output_layer_neurons))
    self.bias1= np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.05, size=self.hiddenlayer_neurons)
    self.bias2=np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.05, size= self.output_layer_neurons)
    return self.weights1,self.weights2,self.bias1,self.bias2

  def sigmoid(self,x):
    sigma=1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return sigma
  
  def softmax(self,inputs):
    inputs=inputs.astype(np.float)
    inputs=np.vectorize(inputs)
    f=np.exp(inputs) / float(sum(np.exp(inputs)))
    #f2 = np.vectorize(f)
    return f

  def forwardpropagation(self):
    self.weights1,self.weights2,self.bias1,self.bias2=self.weightlayers()

    self.bias1=(np.reshape(self.bias1,(-1,1))).T
    self.bias2=(np.reshape(self.bias2,(-1,1))).T
    print(self.bias1.ndim)
    #self.sigmoid=self.sigmoid()
    self.adj=self.adj.T
    self.input= self.adj.dot(self.feature).dot(self.weights1) + (self.bias1)
    print(self.input.shape)
    self.sigmaactivation= self.sigmoid(self.input)
    self.hiddeninput=(self.sigmaactivation @ self.weights2 ) + (self.bias2)
    self.output=self.softmax(self.hiddeninput)
    return self.output
```

For the softmax function it is throwing the above mentioned error.
Following previous answers for somewhat similar question I tried to vectorize and convert it to float.But that does't seen to work.

When I vectorize it, I get this error :

```
TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type vectorize which has no callable exp method.
```

Comment: what is the dimension of the input?   
can you please add an example of it and an expected output?   
If I understand correctly, you're asking only about the function 'softmax'.
posting all of your code makes it confusing and more difficult to help you.
I suggest, next time, you limit your question to the relevant part of your code.
It would also help if you tell us which line in your code throws the error you're asking about

Comment: Show the traceback!  I suspect the use of `float()`.  Why's it there?  Why the `np.vectorize`?  You  didn't read that function''s docs.

Comment: @hpaulj https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680402/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-plot-sh?rq=1

Comment: In the link, `vectorize` takes a `function` that only works with a scalar, and returns one that works with an array.  You aren't doing that!.  You haven't shown what `inputs` is, but the `astype` method implies that it's an array.  `np.vectorize` doesn't make sense that way.  Stop trying to use `np.vectorize`; it's not helping you.

Comment: When debugging, the first step is to identify which expression is giving the problem.  Then check the function docs.  Web search for similar error message should not be the first step.

Comment: Input is sparse numpy matrix.

Comment: @hpaulj yes.I got that. How do I get out of it now?

Comment: @hpaulj I will keep a note of this comment.Thank you so much for this tip, that is very sensible. I am usually looking up for answers in stackoverflow or orther similar forums.I will  try to apply this in the current problem.

Comment: sparse matrix?  As in scipy.sparse?  Or just numpy with lots of zeros?  How was it created?

Comment: The input it is a product of a scipy sparse matrix converted to numpy with another numpy matrix( it is basically output of the final layer of neural network).It is a2d numpy matrix of size 2708*49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `inputs` as 2d numeric array, you don't need all that vectorize or float conversion.

Consider a small 2d array (integer dtype, but doesn't matter):

```
In [110]: arr = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [111]: np.exp(arr)
Out[111]: 
array([[  1.        ,   2.71828183,   7.3890561 ],
       [ 20.08553692,  54.59815003, 148.4131591 ]])
```

`sum` is a python function, that does 1d summation - note the result is (3,) shape array.  Trying to do a scalar `float` conversion on that produces your error:

```
In [112]: sum(np.exp(arr))
Out[112]: array([ 21.08553692,  57.31643186, 155.8022152 ])
In [113]: float(sum(np.exp(arr)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-113-0972ef0e1a76>", line 1, in <module>
    float(sum(np.exp(arr)))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

`np.sum` does the sum on all values, returning one value.  That's float, but that isn't important.

```
In [114]: np.sum(np.exp(arr))
Out[114]: 234.2041839862982
```

That can be used to scale the individual values:

```
In [115]: f=np.exp(arr)
     ...: f/np.sum(f)
Out[115]: 
array([[0.00426978, 0.01160646, 0.03154963],
       [0.08576079, 0.23312201, 0.63369132]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I learnt two important things.Thank you:)